# How do you change the desired accuracy of a TS object in PETSc?

Tags: petsc, time-integration

I'm currently getting very long propagation times when attempting to use the Time Stepping propagators in Petsc 3.2, and in the interest of speeding things up, I'm curious how I can reduce the accuracy (or see what it is in the first place) to speed it up.

Comment: Are you solving a linear or nonlinear system of equations at each time step?

Comment: Linear, is TS for linear propagation? or just for non-linear propagation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### nonlinear systems of equations

In general, the `PETSc TS` propagators solve a nonlinear system of equations at each time step, so you would need to access the `SNES` object and modify its accuracy tolerance there.  See the documentation on [`SNESSetFromOptions`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/SNES/SNESSetFromOptions.html) for a list of the command line options available to you for adjusting the solver tolerances.

#### linear system of equations

PETSc doesn't expose the `KSP` object belonging to `TS` in the same way at the command-line, @JedBrown or @MattKnepley may be able to comment on why.  Programmatically, you can:

[`TSGetKSP(ts, &ksp);`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/TS/TSGetKSP.html)

[`KSPSetTolerances(ksp, rtol, abstol, dtol, maxits;`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/KSP/KSPSetTolerances.html)

Comment: What about for a linear system of equations?